# Where can I find a copy of Serre's Cours au college de France 1985-1986?

Tags: reference-request, abelian-varieties, galois-representations

Hi,

I was wondering: where might I be able to find a copy of this work online?

And are there any other resources for the proof of the open image theorem for abelian varieties with endomorphism ring equal to $\mathbb{Z}$? It seems like the only proof exists in sketch format in the above notes, and in letters between Serre and others.

Comment: There is a 5-page summary of this Cours in Serre's complete works Vol 4, is this the "proof in sketch format" you're referring to ?

Comment: Serre explicitly writes in a note in this Vol 4 that this Cours has not been published, but an overview of the proofs are given in letters to D. Bertrand, M-F. Vignéras and K. Ribet (also to be found in this volume).